# How to include the path of /share folder into Environment variables

Tags: linux, centos

I am trying to install some packages under my own directory since I cannot install it in /usr. I have already finished the installation and found it in my home directory.

For the folders /bin, /lib, I added these paths into $PATH and $LD_LIBRARY_PATH. My question is where should I include the path of the other folders such as /share and /share/aclocal? Or do I have to include the path to some $XXXPATH?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to add a directory to your default path, you do `PATH=$PATH:[your absolute path here]`. Then if you wish to make this permanent for your user, you can add this command to your `~/.bashrc` so that it gets automatically executed.

Note that you need the **absolute** path, so if you wish to give a reference to your home folder, you prepend it with `$HOME/`.

Comment: This person was asking about `share/`, but your answer is about `PATH`